# How to input a numpy array to a neural network in pytorch?

Tags: python, numpy, pytorch, numpy-ndarray

This is the neural network that I defined

```
class generator(nn.Module):
def __init__(self, n_dim, io_dim):
    super().__init__()
    self.gen = nn.Sequential(
        nn.Linear(n_dim,64),
        nn.LeakyReLU(.01),
        nn.Linear(64, io_dim),
    )

def forward(self, x):
    return self.gen(x)
#The input x is:
x = numpy.random.dirichlet([10,6,3],3)
```

Now I want the neural network to take dirichlet distributed samples (sampled using numpy.random.dirichlet([10,6,3],10) ) as an input. How to do that?

Comment: torch.tensor(your_np_array)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using numpy to sample from a dirichlet distribution, use pytorch. Here is the code:

```
y = torch.Tensor([[10,6,3]])
m = torch.distributions.dirichlet.Dirichlet(y)
z=m.sample()

gen = generator(3,3)
gen(z)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert `numpy.array` to `torch.Tensor`:

`input_tensor = torch.from_numpy(x)`

Comment: This converts the datype to float64, which causes problem while initializing the network.

Comment: You can convert the tensor to any type you need, `input_tensor = input_tensor.type(torch.LongTensor)`.

Answer (score 0):

To input a NumPy array to a neural network in PyTorch, you need to convert `numpy.array` to `torch.Tensor`. To do that you need to type the following code.

```
input_tensor = torch.from_numpy(x)
```

After this, your `numpy.array` is converted to `torch.Tensor`.