# how to predict with pretrained model in pytorch

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, pytorch, python-imaging-library

i am trying to translate this https://github.com/piiswrong/deep3d/blob/master/deep3d.ipynb in pytorch

```
import os
import numpy as np
import cv2
import torch
from PIL import Image
from images2gif import writeGif

net = torch.jit.load("deep3d_v1.0_640x360_cpu.pt")
net.eval()

shape = (384, 160)
img = cv2.imread('demo.jpg')
raw_shape = (img.shape[1], img.shape[0])
img = cv2.resize(img, shape)

X = img.astype(np.float32).transpose((2,0,1))
X = X.reshape((1,)+X.shape)
test_iter = np.array(X)
Y = net.predict(test_iter)

right = np.clip(Y.squeeze().transpose((1,2,0)), 0, 255).astype(np.uint8)
right = Image.fromarray(cv2.cvtColor(right, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB))
left = Image.fromarray(cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB))
writeGif('demo.gif', [left, right], duration=0.08)
```

i got `AttributeError: 'RecursiveScriptModule' object has no attribute 'predict'`

i have also tried `net(test_iter)`
and got `RuntimeError: forward() Expected a value of type 'Tensor' for argument 'imgs' but instead found type 'ndarray'.`

what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I would stick with `net(test_iter)` to predict and just use

```
Y = net(torch.from_numpy(test_iter))
```

as this converts the `numpy.ndarray` to a Tensor, see [here](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.from_numpy.html)

Also similar questions: [Similar Questions 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65017261/how-to-input-a-numpy-array-to-a-neural-network-in-pytorch)